# Retrieve page content and pass to PHP?

Tags: pages, content, the-content

I'm new to WP but not PHP.

I've a custom page that I have a PHP call to do some processing on the page content.

`the_content()` even when enclosed in a function call

```
<?php do_something(the_content()  ); ?>
```

`echo`s the page content.

How do I get the page data without so I can send it to a php function?

Answer (score 0):

[`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) *does* echo the content. That is stated in the Codex-- "**Displays** the contents of the current post", emphasis mine. Use [`get_the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) instead, to return a string that you can manipulate.

Be aware that `get_the_content` does not run all of the same filter as `the_content`. Again [from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content):

> If you use plugins that filter content (`add_filter('the_content')`),
>   then this will not apply the filters, unless you call it this way
>   (using `apply_filters`):
>
> ```
> <?php apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content( $more_link_text,> $stripteaser, $more_file )) ?>
> ```

Comment: Perfect many thanks. I'm finding getting to grips with the lexian used is the hard bit with WP.

Comment: Frequently, `the_` echoes, `get_` returns a string, but I think there are exceptions.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I find the tricky part is remembering when it's `get_the_` vs. just `get_` (like `get_the_content()` or `get_permalink()`).

Comment: @PatJ : Yes, I know. `get_permalink` gets me all the time.